# How to use uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 viewcontrollers the second one is added to the first using 
`viewcontroller1.m` :

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];    
vc2.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 740, 695, 245);
```

now I want to navigate from the second to my third viewcontroller , I used  in my  `viewcontroller2.m` :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

but didn't work.  This is what I want to do  : viewcontroller1-->viewcontroller2(navigate and pass an object to viewcontroller3)-->viewcontroller3

Comment: Why are you using presentModalViewController: ?

Comment: my second viewcontroller should be a modal view , that I added it to my first viewcontroller

Comment: Are you wanting to use a navigation controller for the views you will display in the modal view?

Comment: I want to dissmiss the modal view and then navigate to my third viewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

View controllers do not normally bring an UINavigationController by default. When you are presenting a modal view controller, you are losing that source's navigation controller. You can create a new navigation controller, associate it with vc2, and present that modal view controller modally. something like:

```
UINavigationController *controller=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: this should be added in my  viewcontroller1.m when I add the sosond view to the first one?